# Django CreateView Auto Login

Tags: python, django

Using Django's CreateView I would like to login the user when they have registered. I found the best place for this is by overriding the `get_success_url` method.

This is what I have tried:

```
def get_success_url(self):
        user = self.form.get_user()
        login(self.request, user)
```

But it appears that self does not have the user in it and I get the error:

```
object has no attribute 'form'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the view that is responsible for registration add the following code if the registration is successfull:

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
user = authenticate(username=request.POST['username'], password=request.POST['password'])
if user is not None:
    if user.is_active:
        login(request, user)
        redirect('logged_in_url')
    else:
        redirect('user_not_active_url')
else:
    redirect('bad_username_or_password_url')
```